# problems with UIViewController switching

Tags: ios, multithreading, uiviewcontroller

I have a little problem with an application.
When I switch the Views there will be a time delay about 3 to 10 seconds, after this app run two sorting algorythmen. (Quick and Bubblesort) in an extra thread. I dont know where the problem exists.

Here the code snippet:

```
[alert show];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, (unsigned long)NULL), ^(void) {
     time = [Sort sortRuns:(int)slider_durchlaeufe.value WithCapacity:(int)slider_ArraySize.value Reference:alert]; //time is a global reference to my Time object
     [self setDataForStatistik]; // a Method to set the statisik for the next view 
     [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:true];
  });
```

I think the failure is in this code snippet.

I hope you can help me.

Robybyte

Answer (score 0):

You need to make UI updates (or any changes that could trigger UI updates) on the main queue. You will see a good deal of this nested "async to background queue then async to main queue" when looking at code samples.

```
[alert show];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, (unsigned long)NULL), ^(void) {
     time = [Sort sortRuns:(int)slider_durchlaeufe.value WithCapacity:(int)slider_ArraySize.value Reference:alert]; //time is a global reference to my Time object
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         [self setDataForStatistik]; // a Method to set the statisik for the next view 
         [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:true];
     });
});
```

Hope that helps.